# Latency issue for application on HTC ONE developed using Sencha Touch 2.1(Android 4.0.x)

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have developed an application using Sencha Touch 2.1 Framework. The application being installed on the HTC ONE device running on Android 4.0.x version.

It is observe that app's response time is very slow while
 1. Traversing from one screen to another screen
 2. While fetching data from server
 3. After a tap on any icon, loading mask takes time to get displayed
 4. Due to screen transition is taking time, the header of previous screen gets displayed on current screen momentarily and then only the header of current screen is displayed.

The app is working appropriately on the Samsung Galaxy S2/S3 running on same android version.Appreciate any help in this regards.

Browsing internet on this topic gave me couple of links which points to turn off "toggle Ciphering". But that didn't helped either. The links mentioned below.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1118017
http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-improve-slow-data-speed-on-htc-sensation-data-latency-fix/

Comment: why u give down vote??

Comment: Yeah... I am also wondering about the same. If this question being already discussed please point me to one. Thanks.

Comment: Would like to know if there is any other alternative to solve this apart from applying the CSS mentioned below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the below CSS to the component like titlebars, panel of home screen resolved the issue.

```
.x-panel {
   -webkit-perspective: 1000;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```