# Sencha Touch 2.0 - Back UI Button not clickable on Android browser HTC One Android 4.2.1

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Its not possible to click the back button used in Navigation Bar on native Android browser on HTC One. In Chrome it works. I only experienced this problem on newer HTC One with Android 4.2.1

I see its mentioned in the Sencha bug list, but doesnt seem to have been fixed.
http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.1/release-notes.html

```
  The Back/Forward UI buttons still use webkit-masks and needs to be replaced.
```

I using Sencha Touch 2.0, had have problems when trying to upgrade, so have postponed that job. Anyone know how a workaround so I can make it work in Sencha Touch 2.0 ?

A somehow related post is found in Sencha Forum, but workaround solution is only for MessageBoxs

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?262324-Sencha-Messagebox-and-Overlay-Problems-on-HTC-One-Browser

Comment: please try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16774117/1911784

Comment: Thanks. I ended up upgrading to Sencha 2.2, then it worked